# Javascript button stacking, questionnaire

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to create a questionnaire kind of thing. But I want my layout to be slightly different than most. So, I would like to have a question box, and multiple choices underneath it (also boxes (question and answer boxes all images)). I have so far a single question (with answers) working and outputting the answer elsewhere on the site.

The thing I require help with is once I click on an answer box, I would like a new question and multi-choice answers to appear in place of the first.

Here are the fundamentals of my idea: http://www.sn0wy0wl.com/quest.html

I would also like to be able to store these answers to be able to call on them all later (for a confirmation of answers), though that can be a story for another day.

Any input would be greatly appreciated,

regs; sn0wy

Comment: are all the questions/answers within the page/script initially, or will you be loading them through an ajax call?

Comment: Michael, my question is how do I make it so that when a user clicks on any of the 3 answers presented by question 1, that question 2 and 3 new answers will appear in-place of them - this should be possible to do various times (with around 7 questions intended).

Comment: James, currently all questions are currently loaded through the page/script. But hopefully once I have this pinned down, I will have them loaded externally for tidy-coding sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at http://knockoutjs.com/ with it you can create a viewmodel to hold the question, and observablearray of possible answers and bind the click in the view to the change the question. Something a bit like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Knockout Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            function QuestionnaireViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

                //Some dummy model data, probably want to load this from an ajax call
                var questions = [
                    {
                        caption: 'How do you like Knockout.js?',
                        answers: [
                            { caption: 'It sucks!' },
                            { caption: 'It rules!' }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        caption: 'But seriously, it is pretty cool right?',
                        answers: [
                            { caption: 'Ok, it is pretty awsome' },
                            { caption: 'I told you man, it rocks!' }
                        ]
                    }
                ];

                //Setup observable properties
                self.currentQuestion = new ko.observable(questions[0]);
                self.progress = new ko.observableArray();

                //Add a command
                self.selectQuestion = function (answer) {
                    self.progress.push({ question: questions[currentQuestionIndex].caption, answer: answer.caption });

                    currentQuestionIndex++;
                    if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.length) {
                        self.currentQuestion(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Your done');
                    }
                };
            };

            $(document).ready(function () {
                //Apply bindings
                ko.applyBindings(new QuestionnaireViewModel());
            });
        </script>

        <div data-bind="with:currentQuestion">
            <h1 data-bind="text:caption"></h1>
            <ul data-bind="foreach:answers">
                <li data-bind="text:caption, click:$root.selectQuestion"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="foreach:progress">
            <div>
                For question 
                <b data-bind="text:question"></b>
                you selected 
                <b data-bind="text:answer"></b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </head>
</html>
```

Obviously this needs a bit of refactoring and tidying up, but hopefully you get the drift. The knockout site has some great documentation and examples too.

Comment: This is brilliant, Simon, thank you very much!
With this I will be able to manipulate the questions/answers and even output all the answers how and where I want.
Thanks for the knockout link too, I'm sure it will provide me with additional ideas and aides. Kudos!

Comment: (Sorry, I can't vote up until I have 15 rep, I'll return to vote once I've earned it)

Answer (score 0):

This is a multifaceted question.

> The thing I require help with is once I click on an answer box, I
>   would like a new question and multi-choice answers to appear in place
>   of the first.

Without a database retrieving the question, you can use hide / show attributes with javascript to give flow.

With database you will need intermediate layer to preform request to retrieve question set.

> I would also like to be able to store these answers to be able to call
>   on them all later (for a confirmation of answers), though that can be
>   a story for another day.

Without database you can use sessions.

With databases you will need to set up user, questions, answers tables kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks Dan, do you recommend setting up a database for this whole procedure, or is it truly down to preference?

As it stands, I have not set one up, so with that in mind, would hide/show attributes work for multiple layers, as opposed to just alternating layers? If so, that could be the simplest solution here.

Regarding storing the answers, I will look further into 'sessions' if I do not venture into a database.

-Thanks for your help

Comment: depends on the needs of the project.

Comment: Sorry for my premature reply and sloppy presentation, it seems I've yet to get to grips with the basics of this site's comment box haha.